# self.$expandAttributes is not a function with Sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

i've try to add master and details object to MySQL with Sequelize and i got the error like;

TypeError: self.$expandAttributes is not a function
   at conformOptions (/Desktop/git/ss-portal-server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:243:10)
   at conformInclude (/Desktop/git/ss-portal-server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:300:5)

Reference from;
https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/docs/docs/associations.md

Anyone know where is my error.
Many thanks

Sample code;

```
var contactModel = global.sequelize.define('Contact', {
                Email: global.Sequelize.STRING,
                FirstName: global.Sequelize.STRING,
                LastName: global.Sequelize.STRING,
                BirthDate: global.Sequelize.DATE,
                PhoneId: global.Sequelize.BIGINT,
                AddressId: global.Sequelize.BIGINT,
                IsActived: global.Sequelize.BOOLEAN
            }, {
                tableName: 'CONTACT',
                timestamps: false
            });

var addressModel = global.sequelize.define('Address', {
                CountryId: global.Sequelize.INTEGER,
                City: global.Sequelize.STRING,
                Line1: global.Sequelize.STRING,
                Line2: global.Sequelize.STRING,
                PostalCode: global.Sequelize.STRING,
                State: global.Sequelize.STRING,
                IsActived: global.Sequelize.BOOLEAN
            }, {
                tableName: 'ADDRESSES',
                timestamps: false
            });

var Addresses = contactModel.hasMany(addressModel, {as: 'addresses'});

contactModel.create({
        Email: "email1.test@gmail.com",
        FirstName: "f1",
        LastName: "l1",
        BirthDate: "1990-01-02",
        addresses: [
            {
                CountryId: 1,
                City: "San",
                Line1: "Address line 1",
                Line2: "Address line 2",
                PostalCode: "MKD922M",
                State: "ADD",
                IsActived: true
            },
            {
                CountryId: 2,
                City: "San1",
                Line1: "Address line 1",
                Line2: "Address line 2",
                PostalCode: "M323M",
                State: "ADD222",
                IsActived: true
            }
        ],
        IsActived: true
},{
    include: [{ model: Addresses, as: 'addresses'}]
}).then(function(c) {
    console.log(c);
    callback(null, c);
});
```

Comment: Did you figure out what your problem was here? I think the problem is in your 'include' line but no idea how to solve it because I'm having the same problem like.

Comment: I got the same error. If replace `include: [Addresses]` will work, but I want to try nested create 1toN relationships.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. I changed `include: [{ model: Addresses, as: 'addresses'}]` to `include: [{ model: Addresses}]`. Look at the example below

```
const User = sequelize.define('user', {
  username: Sequelize.STRING,
});

const Address = sequelize.define('add', {
  address: Sequelize.STRING,
}, {
    tableName: 'adds123',
  });

const Designation = sequelize.define('designation', {
  designation: Sequelize.STRING,
});

User.hasOne(Address);
User.hasMany(Designation);

sequelize.sync({ force: true })
  .then(() => User.create({
    username: 'test123',
    add: {
      address: 'this is dummy address'
    },
    designations: [
      { designation: 'designation1' },
      { designation: 'designation2' },
    ],
  }, { include: [Address, Designation] }))
  .then(user => {
    User.findAll({
      include: [{
        model: Address
      }, {
        model: Designation
      }
      ],
    }).then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
    });
  });
```